# Issues with an interface treating a synchronous action as async

Tags: c#, interfaces, async

Let's say I'm trying to write a library that abstracts certain actions. In this example I want to turn a light on or off. There could be hundreds of different kinds of lights that are controlled in lots of different ways, so I have an interface like so:

```
public interface ILight
{
    bool TurnOnLight();
    bool TurnOffLight();
}
```

Or like:

```
public interface ILight
{
    Task<bool> TurnOnLight();
    Task<bool> TurnOffLight();
}
```

The design of the interface is that calling the method should turn on/off the light and then return a boolean saying if it was successful or not. The amount of time this takes is indeterminate.

The desire/goal is to have a **common interface** that developers who are unfamiliar with the hardware can use. They'd just call `TurnOnLight` and get a return if it worked or not, regardless of the implementation.

The issue is that, in the implementation of the interface, some of the implementations involve async operations, and others do not. These "restrictions" exist in the various 3rd party libraries used to communicate with the lights. Whether or not these libraries are performing "real" async operations is unknown, just that they return an awaitable task with results.

```
Library1.TurnOnLight();
```

vs

```
await Library2.TurnOnLight();
```

The developer using this stuff shouldn't have to worry about what type of light is being used, just that they want to turn it on or off. That makes me think I'd end up with an interface and implementation like:

```
public interface ILight
{
    Task<bool> TurnOnLight();
    Task<bool> TurnOffLight();
}

public class Light1 : ILight
{
    public Task<bool> TurnOnlight()
    {
        bool result = Library1.TurnOnLight();
        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
}

public class Light2 : ILight
{
    public async Task<bool> TurnOnlight()
    {
        return await Library2.TurnOnLight();
    }
}
```

I've seen some people reference using a similar design pattern, and others who say it's bad practice to have something return a task that is synchronous. I lean towards the implementation I've got here, are there gotchas or issues with this design that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 2):

To point out the English semantics: "can await things" is not synonymous with "*will* await things".

Just because an `async` method is able to return control to the owning thread for the time being (i.e. while awaiting something), doesn't mean that it invariably will do so.
As a basic example, if your code starts a task, performs some other work, and then awaits that task, it's possible that the task already finished by the time your code awaits it, which means that your code will never actually wait for the task to complete, it will immediately continue with the rest of its work.

Your `ILight` hits on this precise distinction. It enforces that any light which implements the interface must make their method **awaitable**. However, the interface does not in fact enforce that any light which implements the interface must actually *await something*.

Your approach is perfectly fine.

> I've seen some people [..] say it's bad practice to have something return a task that is synchronous.

That statement does not account for cases like your example, where you're trying to define a blanket interface that accounts for both synchronous and asynchronous implementations.

If *none* of the implementations make use of `await`, be it in the method body or a submethod below it, then using `async` is indeed irrelevant.

Although even then you could still argue that introducing `async` is the first step of upgrading the library's contract to being `async`-friendly, before actually rewriting the method bodies themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are some *gotchas*, indeed!

Before all, let's agree on something, it is not a good idea to expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods ([quite authoritative source](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/)).

Long story short, regarding why:

- The simplest of reasons is that you are pretty much spawning a new `Task`, burdening the current Thread pool and this is something that your consumer **just might not want**. If all you do is `Task.Run(...)`, then there is nothing stopping your consumer from doing just that, wherever they deem absolutely necessary (usually close to the UI, which is where async makes all the difference).
- Careless usage of your methods (e.g. synchronously waiting with `.Wait()` or `.Result`) may lead to deadlocks (though you can *hack* your way using `ConfigureAwait(false)` wherever possible...see [Avoiding Context](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and [Preventing the Deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and make **absolutely sure you understand why this works**).
- You could expose asynchronous interfaces when you are dealing with **pure/naturally asynchronous methods** (like, e.g. I/O... generally, methods that **are not CPU-bound**). The idea behind that is that CPU resources are **precious and scarce**, therefore, you should not make decisions *on behalf of your consumer*).

Now, regarding your situation, it seems you may be out of luck, since 3rd party libraries are asynchronous anyway. Based on how deep knowledge you have about this library, if you are certain that their methods are *naturally* asynchronous (and implemented as such), you can definitely offer asynchronous abstractions. The general advice that I could give you, at least when you are **stuck** (e.g. with 3rd party libraries or code you have no control over), is to **avoid lying about the true underlying implementations**. You just [cannot abstract `async` efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41438867/10102452), it runs [all the way down/up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29809054/10102452).

I am afraid I cannot offer more suggestions (note that I am avoiding the word *advice* as I am not much of an expert on all things `async`) unless you further elaborate.

## EDIT/UPDATE:

Based on your [comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/408345/issues-with-an-interface-treating-a-synchronous-action-as-async/408353?noredirect=1#comment899056_408353), what I am suggesting is not to provide two flavors of everything (a synchronous and an asynchronous counterpart), but to provide only **one** of everything, based on what the library call is: use `async` when abstracting a method that is already `async` or you know is *naturally asynchronous*, otherwise avoid asynchronous wrappers, keep everything else synchronous so that the decision can be taken further up the "call stack", whether the called method should be wrapped in asynchronous methods or not.

If you want to hide your implementations behind an interface and have some of them be `async` and some others **not `async`**, I am afraid that your only option what you are proposing.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19696462/10102452) answer pretty much covers your case (#1 in specific). Some of your implementations are asynchronous, while others are not! So, for what it's worth, your proposed design is your best bet. It also allows you to change your synchronous implementations to truly asynchronous in the future.

Comment: All good advice (I've read several of the articles you linked before), but I feel like this is more of generic guidelines of when to use async, and less about the specific situation. The interface implementation(s) are like plugins for interfacing with different hardware, and no, I don't know enough about the dozens of vendor specific libraries to know how "true" their async is. Are you suggesting that there be twice as many functions, for both asyc and not, and that the developer should know enough about the individual devices to use them differently? That's what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: @cost I have updated my answer. But you seem to imply that you need a **common** interface, implementations of which may or may not be asynchronous, is that right?

Comment: Yes, I need/want a common interface so the developer can just call `TurnLightOn` and not worry about any other details. I'll update my question too. Some, but not all of the internal implementations, use libraries that have async calls to return if it was a success or not. Because of that, I have to have Task/await all the way up so that the returned bool can be passed up. Other libraries just return a bool.

Comment: About your most recent edit with the link, that was one place I found that makes that recommendation. I haven't been able to find too much dialogue about it though, which is why I was looking for extra thoughts here. Thanks for your input!

Comment: I have updated my answer again. Yes, based on your requirements, I think your proposed design is the most advantageous at the moment. Maybe we can wait to see what others have to propose.

Comment: Bullet point 1 is a "pass the buck" (or [NIMBY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIMBY)) argument. _Every_ method body can defer _any_ job to its caller. But if you use that as a basis of deciding not to do something, then you end up doing nothing at all. That's not to say that you should do _everything_, but the decision on what to do is situational and you can't just argue a blanket "[this] shouldn't be done by [this] method" across all possible contexts. *The interface* decides what the consumer can and cannot expect, and OP is the interface designer in this scenario, so they can choose async.

Comment: @Flater No, I'd really not have it in **anyone's** backyard. Bullet point 1 is mostly someone else's suggestion and I agree with it because I would feel somewhat tricked if I'd call a method that returns a `Task` and happily write code that awaits it, trying to do other things, only to find out that my UI is still blocked (because the method is probably CPU-bound, takes quite a bit of time and _does not really run asynchronously at all_). My 1st bullet point simply suggests: "**Don't wrap synchronous methods in `Task.Run(...)` and return this `Task`**", but OP is not doing this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I understand my previous answer was not very helpful. Let me try again...

There are **naturally asynchronous** operations, and operations that are not naturally asynchronous.

```cs
public async Task TurnTheLightsOn()
{
    await _light.TurnOnLight();
}
```

MSDN [informs us](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model#BKMK_Threads)

> The async and await keywords don't cause additional threads to be
> created. Async methods don't require multithreading because an async
> method doesn't run on its own thread. The method runs on the current
> synchronization context and uses time on the thread only when the
> method is active. [...]

If no additional threads are created, how is asynchrony "simulated"? It's right in there: ...**an async method doesn't run on its own thread**. That is, of course, **unless it has to**.

When you provide a `Task` returning method, you **may** be spawning a new thread, or you **may** have a naturally asynchronous operation, but a message that you **do** send is that your call is **non-blocking**. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12786836/10102452) for an example of something going wrong because of this misunderstanding.

Your `Task<bool>`-returning method that exposes the synchronous `TurnOnLight()` library method as a *seemingly asynchronous operation* is practically a trick. So, going back to the previous consideration, this method really doesn't run on its own thread (as per MSDN). Which thread does it run on, then? That's right, it runs on the calling thread. If you `await _light.TurnOnLight()` and the fake-Task method is called, regardless of the `await`, the call is **blocking**, because the only "exit-point" in your implementation is the `return Task.FromResult<bool>(...)` line of code.

So, if your `TurnOnLight()` method is **CPU-bound** (fancy term for "takes quite a bit of cpu time to complete", alternatively a "long-running" method), calling it in a context where non-blocking calls are a requirement  (e.g. to have a responsive GUI) can lead to funny code. Any developer finding that out will end up doing something along the lines (well, OK, almost... just vary to taste):

```cs
public async Task SwitchTheLightsOn()
{
    //Update UI element notifying the user that the light is being turned on.
    //Also update UI indicator of "work-being-done".
    //...

    bool lightsOn = await Task<bool>.Run(() =>
    {
        //This call is blocking, for some reason, so it is necessary to
        //send it to the "background" for execution, otherwise, the UI
        //doesn't update while waiting...
        return _light.TurnOnLight();
    });
    
    //Update UI elements back to the visual indication of an idle state.
    //Inform the UI about success or failure using the lightsOn variable.
    //...
}
```

In short, make sure that your `TurnOnLight()` method **is not CPU-bound**. Otherwise, you should find a way to indicate that this method is long-running.